# Average cost of successful search in hash table in chaining

Tags: performance, algorithm, hashmap, chaining, asymptotic-complexity

I have searched every where for this but I can't understand why is it O(1+a/2)
where a is the load factor. Can some one explain this step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number of elements in your hash table be `n`.

It means there are `n/a` total number of cells (/lines) in the hash table, each holds a list of elements. This is the definition of load factor.

So, the expected number of elements assossiated to each such cell is `n/(n/a) = a`.

A linear search in an unsorted list needs to traverse half of the elements until it finds the correct one on average (and we assume it is a succesful search), so it needs to traverse `a/2` elements.

The `1` factor comes from accessing the correct list in the hash table itself.

Comment: A linear search in an unsorted list needs to traverse half of the elements. This is what i don't understand. Why is that so? It may be that required element is at the end of list so why we need to traverse only half?

Comment: It's on average: sometimes it's the first, sometimes the last, on average it's half the number of elements.

Comment: @user4129542 I omitted the word 'average', which is important here. Intuitively, it has 50% chance to be at last elements and 50% to be at firsts.  (More thorough proof can be found in the proof the the [expected value of uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case) of 0,...,U is U/2